# Python ctypes function returns ValueError when C function returns NULL

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm creating an interface to a C library in Python using ctypes, and I have a C function returns a char** (array of C-strings) normally but returns NULL on an error. I do not know the length of the array being returned, the last entry will be NULL. I have tried multiple types for the restype:

```
restype = POINTER(c_char_p)
restype = POINTER(POINTER(c_char))
```

Both of these work fine when the C function returns successfully (with slightly different processing afterward). But both have issues when the C function has an error and returns NULL. I was expecting the return value to be None, but instead a get a pointer to byte string of a stack trace that ends "ValueError: NULL pointer access".

What should the restype be for a C function that converts a char** to an array of strings on success but converts NULL to None on an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple options:

- Use a `c_void_p` result.  It will be coerced to `None` if `NULL` is returned, else cast it to `POINTER(c_char_p)` to extract the strings.
- Use `POINTER(c_char_p)` to extract the strings.  Wrap in a `try/except` and return `None` on `ValueError`.

Either works.  I prefer using a wrapper to make the function behave as desired and it ensures that if the strings were dynamically allocated they are freed once extracted as Python strings.

Example:

**test.c**

```c
#if defined(_WIN32)
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

API char** get_strings(int fail) {
    if(fail)
        return NULL;
    char** p = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
    p[0] = _strdup("test1");
    p[1] = _strdup("test2");
    p[2] = NULL;
    return p;
}

API void free_strings(char** p) {
    if(p) {
        char** tmp = p;
        while(*p)
            free(*p++);
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

**test.py**

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.get_strings.argtypes = c_int,
dll.get_strings.restype = POINTER(c_char_p)
dll.free_strings.argtypes = POINTER(c_char_p),
dll.free_strings.restype = None

def get_strings(fail):
    p = dll.get_strings(fail)
    result = []
    try:
        for s in p:
            if s is None: break
            result.append(s)
        return result
    except ValueError:
        return None
    finally:
        dll.free_strings(p)

print(get_strings(0))
print(get_strings(1))
```

Output:

```
[b'test1', b'test2']
None
```

Comment: I went with switching the restype to c_void_p and then casting to POINTER(POINTER(c_char)), because that mostly matched up what I was doing before. And that worked. 

I almost want to file a bug report over this, I would think NULL should get coerced to None on both of the original return types I had as well. I did check for None, it didn't work because there was some value there.